# Не могу добавить другие команды в бота python

Tags: python, telegram, бот

При попытке добавить любую команду кроме старта, бот начинает отвечать на все что можно этой же командой.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    keyboard.row('Portal', 'Инфо')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы активировали бота', reply_markup=keyboard)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])


@bot.message_handler(commands=['getme'])
def getme_message(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    keyboard.row('Portal', 'Инфо')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'лол', reply_markup=keyboard)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя лишние два декоратора `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])`
То есть у тебя функция `def getme_message(message):`Вызывается когда приходит любой текст, тебе нужно вообще убрать их, что бы стало так

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    keyboard.row('Portal', 'Инфо')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы активировали бота', reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['getme'])
def getme_message(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    keyboard.row('Portal', 'Инфо')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'лол', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: после такого не работает весь остальной код. только команды

Comment: Там нужно полностью код смотреть, но то что я написал это точно правильный совет

Comment: можно как-то с тобой связаться?